# Use shapeless to merge two instances of the same case class

Tags: scala, shapeless

I want to merge an update instance of a class into a base instance, choosing the field of the update instance over the base instance if that field is "empty" in the base instance. The example below merges `base` and `update`:

```
case class Foo(a: Option[Int], b: List[Int], c: Option[Int])

val base = Foo(None, Nil, Some(0))
val update = Foo(Some(3), List(4), None)

merge(base,update) == Foo(Some(3), List(4), Some(0))
```

I've tried something like this:

```
val g = Generic[Foo]
val aHList = g.to(base)
val bHList = g.to(update)

aHList
  .zipWithIndex
  .map({
    case (l: List, i: Int) => l ++ bHList(i)
    case (o: Option, i: Int) => if (!bHList(i).nonEmpty) {
      updateHList(i)
    } else {
      o
    }
    case (_, i: Int) => updateHList(i)
  })
```

But it turns out the generic `.to` method does not output an `HList` per say but a `Repr`. Any idea how I could achieve my goal?

Thank you !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For specific tasks like this, it is most often easier to create a type class than to dabble with something like a `map` with a `Poly`.

We can represent an update on some `T` as follows :

```
trait Update[T] {
  def apply(base: T, update: T): T
}
```

Now we need to define some instances. How to update a `List` and `Option` and some instances to make it possible to derive an `Update[Foo]` instance.

```
import shapeless._

object Update extends Update0 {
  def apply[A](implicit update: Lazy[Update[A]]): Update[A] = update.value

  implicit def optionUpdate[A]: Update[Option[A]] = 
    new Update[Option[A]] {
      def apply(base: Option[A], update: Option[A]): Option[A] = update orElse base
    }

  implicit def listUpdate[A]: Update[List[A]] = 
    new Update[List[A]] {
      def apply(base: List[A], update: List[A]): List[A] = base ++ update
    }

  implicit def hnilUpdate: Update[HNil] = 
    new Update[HNil] {
      def apply(base: HNil, update: HNil): HNil = HNil
    }

  implicit def hconsUpdate[H, T <: HList](
    implicit updateH: Update[H], updateT: Lazy[Update[T]]
  ): Update[H :: T] = 
    new Update[H :: T] {
      def apply(base: H :: T, update: H :: T): H :: T = 
        updateH(base.head, update.head) :: updateT.value(base.tail, update.tail)
    }
}

trait Update0 {
  implicit def genericUpdate[A, G <: HList](
    implicit gen: Generic.Aux[A, G], updateG: Lazy[Update[G]]
  ): Update[A] =
    new Update[A] {
      def apply(base: A, update: A): A = 
        gen.from(updateG.value(gen.to(base), gen.to(update)))
    }
}
```

We can add some syntax to make it a little bit easier :

```
implicit class UpdateOps[A](val base: A) extends AnyVal {
  def update(change: A)(implicit update: Lazy[Update[A]]): A = 
    update.value(base, change)
}
```

Now we can do :

```
case class Foo(a: Option[Int], b: List[Int], c: Option[Int])

val base = Foo(None, Nil, Some(0))
val update = Foo(Some(3), List(4), None)

base update update // Foo(Some(3),List(4),Some(0))
```

---

We could define an instance for `cats.SemigroupK` or `scalaz.Plus` so we could omit the `Option` and `List` instances, while gaining eg `Update[Vector[Int]]` :

```
import cats.SemigroupK
import cats.implicits._

implicit def semigroupKUpdate[F[_], A](implicit F: SemigroupK[F]): Update[F[A]] =
  new Update[F[A]] {
    def apply(base: F[A], update: F[A]): F[A] = F.combineK(update, base)
  }
```

Comment: Nice solution, thx ! Why are putting `genericUpdate` in a different trait ? Why not have it in Update ?

Comment: Like it is, it should be fine in `Update`. But if for example you want to create a custom `Update[(A, B)]`, the `genericUpdate` needs to be in a `trait` because otherwise you would get ambiguous implicits.

Comment: As for the setup I have a compile error, it can't find the `Update[Foo]` implicit. I have the `Update` trait and object in a file. And the `UpdateOps[A]` in a package object. I import both the package object as well the content of the `Update` object. Looks like it does not find the `GenericUpdate`. On another note, what is `G` for in the `genericUpdate` ?

Comment: My bad, forgot to add implicits for other datatypes. The error mislead me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Poly` and `map` to solve this problem in a very general way. I think the solution is quite elegant.

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.ops.hlist._
import syntax.std.tuple._

trait LowPriority extends Poly1 {
  implicit def default[T, U] = at[(T, U)]{ case (t, u) => t }
}

object ChooseNonEmpty extends LowPriority {
  type OverNone[A] = (None.type, A)
  type OverNil[A] = (Nil.type, A)
  implicit def caseNone[T] = at[OverNone[T]] { case (t, u) => u }
  implicit def caseList[T] = at[OverNil[T]] { case (t, u) => u }
}

object test {
  def merge[C, HF <: Poly, Repr <: HList, ZRepr <: HList, MRepr <: HList](f:HF)(base:C, update:C)
  (implicit
       gen:Generic.Aux[C, Repr],
       zipper:Zip.Aux[Repr :: Repr :: HNil, ZRepr],
       mapper:Mapper.Aux[f.type, ZRepr, MRepr]): C = {

    val basep = gen.to(base)
    val updatep = gen.to(update)

    val zipped = basep zip updatep

    gen.from( (zipped map f).asInstanceOf[Repr])
  }
}
```

Edit: figured out how to match None and Nil object types embedded in Tuples with a Poly. Added it and simplified the code.